# How to apply theme programmatically?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

In XML, my action bar is created like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/myactivity_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

Now I'm trying to create the action bar programmatically but I'm having difficulties to find out how to apply the style. I've tried the following:

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar actionBar = new android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar(getContext());  
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.style.ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_ActionBar, typedValue, true);
actionBar.setTheme(typedValue.data);
```

Unfortunately, this results in a "cannot find symbol" error on `ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_ActionBar`.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: Thanks, it can now find the symbol. But `setTheme` isn't there for `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`. How can I apply the theme now to my `actionBar`? There doesn't seem to be a `setTheme` method...

Comment: Yeah, after I posted that, I realized that that snippet isn't really correct overall. A style is not an attribute, so `resolveAttribute()` isn't applicable. If you want to apply a separate theme to a dynamically created `Toolbar`, you could make use of a `ContextThemeWrapper`, which is what `Toolbar` actually does internally to support the `theme` XML attribute. That is, `new Toolbar(new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_ActionBar))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm now and my action bar created programmatically looks exactly like the XML version! Thanks again!